# PHP: getting and adding number values outside of a loop

Tags: php, time, foreach

I have a project here that I am working on which has a repeater cycling through an album's track listings (names & lengths).

It takes a look at minutes and seconds (written in the format of 00:03:22 for three minutes and twenty-two seconds for example).

Now the goal of this project is to somehow be able to format this user-input number string into some sort of variable which the PHP recognizes as hours:minutes:seconds.

Then as the foreach statement sorts through each track of the album (via the repeater) adds up each track length (in HH:MM:SS Format).

It outputs an end total to display "38 Minutes" (or something to that effect).

Working code sample below (Mind you, it may not be super clean & there is a strong chance this code could be written way shorter), but my big issue here is getting the track totals all added together outside of the foreach loop & tell the user how long the entire length of the album is.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

```
if( have_rows('tracks') ):
$count = count(get_field('tracks'));
$k = 1;
print $count . ' Total Songs';
$songs = get_field('tracks');
if($songs) {
    $z = '00:00:00'; // Initial Time Setting Var
    foreach($songs as $song)
    {
        $sl = $song['length']; /Song Length
        $minutes = strstr($sl, ':', true); // Extract Minutes Value
        if ( strlen($minutes) <= 2 ) { $minutes = '0' . $minutes; } // Format Minutes Value to Dual Digit If Singular
        $seconds = strstr($sl, ':'); // Extract Seconds Value
        $seconds = str_replace(':', '', $seconds); // Remove : Before Seconds
        $new_display = $minutes . ':' . $seconds; // Re-Format Minutes : Seconds
        $full_display = '00:' . $new_display; // Add Hours : Before New Time Display
        // Get Full Display Back To Seconds
        $time = explode(':', $full_display);
        $formatted_secs = ($time[0]*3600) + ($time[1]*60) + $time[2];
        // Do Some Stuff For Me
        echo '<p>Song'. $k .' = ' . $sl . '</p>';
        echo 'Track Time For Track '. $k .' in minuntes is ' . $full_display . ' and is ' . $formatted_secs . ' seconds';
        //$z = $z+= $full_display;
        $k++; // Count
    }
    echo '<br>Total time is ' . $z; // Not Working Regardless
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are dealing with dates and times, it is usually a good idea to use PHP's built-in [`DateTime`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php) class. This also eliminates the need to do all those ugly string manipulations that you are doing and greatly simplifies your code.

```
if (have_rows('tracks')) {    
    $count = count(get_field('tracks'));
    print $count . ' Total Songs';
    $songs = get_field('tracks');
    if ($songs) {
        $start = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i:s', '00:00:00');
        $total_seconds = 0;

        foreach ($songs as $i => $song) {
            $end = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i:s', $song['length']);
            $length = $start->diff($end);
            $seconds = $end->getTimestamp() - $start->getTimestamp();
            $total_seconds += $seconds;

            echo '<p>Song'. ($i + 1) .' = ' . $song['length'] . '</p>';
            echo 'Track Time For Track '. ($i + 1) .' in minuntes is ' . $length->format('%H:%I:%S') . ' and is ' . $seconds . ' seconds';
        }

        echo '<br>Total time is ' . $total_seconds;
    }
}
```

On another note, always use descriptive variable names unless they are simple counters. Using `$z` and `$k` does not describe what these variables are and makes reading your code very difficult for others.

Comment: Mike, you are the man. Your code was super clean and helped me make sense of everything that was going on around it.